# replace two fragments with each other using animation

Tags: android, animation, replace, fragment, child-fragment

I'm just a beginner to native android developing. I have an application in which I have a fragment inside of an activity. This fragment has a header, a footer and in the middle a FrameLayout to display other fragments
XML of the Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fragments.Fragment1">

<!-- Dummy item for focus at startup -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dummy_id"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_section"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/vehicle"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closeBT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/close_button_icon" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/area_for_fragments"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_section"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

</FrameLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_separator_line"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/titular_infractor"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/accept_button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bottom_separator_line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_separator_line"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/accept_button_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_separator_line"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit_vehicle_accept_button"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_button_selector"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_separator_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To show the first fragment I'm using the childFragmentManager:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    TestSearchFragment elf = new TestSearchFragment();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.replace(R.id.area_for_fragments, elf);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

This fragment should simply placed there at the start. After I clicked on the Accept button, the first fragment should slide out of the screen over the top and the new, second fragment should slide in coming from the bottom. I'm using at the moment this code to replace them:

```
FragmentTransaction ft2 = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            TestDetailFragment elf2 = new TestDetailFragment();


            ft2.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
            ft2.replace(R.id.area_for_fragments, elf2);

            ft2.addToBackStack("TEST FRAGMENT TAG")
                    .commit();
```

But for any reason the fragments are replaced and after that, the animation starts. While the animation is going on, the new fragment is sliding out of the screen upsides and the old fragment slides in from the botton. After the Animation is finished the new fragment is displayed.

My Code for the animations:

Slide_in_up.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%"/>
</set>
```

slide_out_up.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

I don't know how to fix it or what the reason is for this crazy replacement.
Hope somebody could help.
Thank you

Comment: Why do you have that - `ft.add(elf, "Search");` ? I think it will cause unpredictable behavior, because you add and replace same fragment in one transaction.

Comment: I tried it out, but then both fragments are displayed at the same time

Comment: I'm sorry, I have misunderstand you...

Comment: I have delete it, but the result is the same. The Fragments are replaced and then an animation starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right solution:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionSearch = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionSearch.add(childSearchFragment, "SEARCH");
        fragmentTransactionSearch.replace(R.id.area_for_fragments, childSearchFragment);
        fragmentTransactionSearch.commit();
```

Thats the start to place the first fragment into the defined `<FrameLayout>`

If you want to replace this childFragment with an other childFragment, then use:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionDetail = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionDetail.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up, R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_down);
        fragmentTransactionDetail.remove(childSearchFragment);
        fragmentTransactionDetail.add(childDetailFragment, "DETAIL");
        fragmentTransactionDetail.replace(R.id.area_for_fragments, childDetailFragment);
        fragmentTransactionDetail.addToBackStack("ShowDetail");
        fragmentTransactionDetail.commit();
```

And as an Extra. If you want to control the BackButtonFunction, then you have to Overwrite the OnBackPressed function in the parentFragment with following code:

```
 if(parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    {   this.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This method would replace the fargments with a custom animation,

```
private void flipToFragment(Fragment showFragment, Fragment hideFragment){
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.anim.card_flip_right_in, R.anim.card_flip_right_out,
                        R.anim.card_flip_left_in, R.anim.card_flip_left_out)
                .hide(hideFragment)
                .show(showFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Following would be the Animation resources to be placed in res/anim ,

1. card_flip_left_in.xml

> ```
>  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>         <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
>         <objectAnimator
>             android:valueFrom="1.0"
>             android:valueTo="0.0"
>             android:propertyName="alpha"
>             android:duration="0" />
>
>         <!-- Rotate. -->
>         <objectAnimator
>             android:valueFrom="-180"
>             android:valueTo="0"
>             android:propertyName="rotationY"
>
>
> android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
>         android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />
>
>
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="0.0"
>         android:valueTo="1.0"
>         android:propertyName="alpha"
>         android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
>         android:duration="1" />
> </set>
> ```

2. card_flip_left_out.xml

> ```
> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <!-- Rotate. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="0"
>         android:valueTo="180"
>         android:propertyName="rotationY"
>         android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
>         android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />
>
>     <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="1.0"
>         android:valueTo="0.0"
>         android:propertyName="alpha"
>         android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
>         android:duration="1" />
> </set>
> ```

3. card_flip_right_in.xml

> ```
>     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="1.0"
>         android:valueTo="0.0"
>         android:propertyName="alpha"
>         android:duration="0" />
>
>     <!-- Rotate. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="180"
>         android:valueTo="0"
>         android:propertyName="rotationY"
>         android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
>         android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />
>
>     <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="0.0"
>         android:valueTo="1.0"
>         android:propertyName="alpha"
>         android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
>         android:duration="1" />
> </set>
> ```

4. card_flip_right_in.xml

> ```
> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <!-- Rotate. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="0"
>         android:valueTo="-180"
>         android:propertyName="rotationY"
>         android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
>         android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />
>
>     <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
>     <objectAnimator
>         android:valueFrom="1.0"
>         android:valueTo="0.0"
>         android:propertyName="alpha"
>         android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
>         android:duration="1" />
> </set>
> ```

Comment: I can't uns object animator: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml

Comment: Your java code isn't working. Fragment is hide but the newer one isn't shown